# How to divide memory on the heap?

Tags: c, heap-memory

Let's say I allocate a large block of memory on the heap. To make it simple lets say its 512 bytes. How would I go about dividing that 512 bytes of memory into 16 blocks of 32 bytes each?

Comment: You question is unclear. Depends how you intend to use/access this "divided" memory. One way is to just to treat it as one 512 byte array and then access each chunk as `&mem[0]`, `&mem[32]`, `&mem[64]`, etc.

Comment: I guess I was undecided on this until you made this comment. I think doing it that way seems the least problematic and easiest to implement. @kaylum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic memory is returned as `void*`. Arithmetic on `void*` is not defined by the standard but you can cast to `char*` when calculating the individual block address. Like:

```
#define BLOCKS 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE 32

int main(void) 
{
    void * m = malloc(BLOCKS * BLOCK_SIZE);
    assert(m != NULL);
    void * dm[BLOCKS];
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKS; ++i) dm[i] = (char*)m + i * BLOCK_SIZE;
    
    // Use the individual blocks, e.g. print their values
    for (int i = 1; i < BLOCKS; ++i) printf("%p \n", dm[i]);
    
    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice: The `BLOCK_SIZE` must take care of alignment requirements for your system.